# Parsing JSON using foreach in JQuery

Tags: jquery

This is code I'm using right now to do AJAX via JQuery:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: linktopage,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    alert(item.productId);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            }
        });
```

where **index = d** and **item = "[{"productId":5284598},{"productId":5790923}]"** but **alert(item.productId)** is undefined, how can i access each productId?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could give us a sample of the returned JSON data.

Comment: this is the returned JSON data: "[{"productId":5284598},{"productId":5790923}]"

Comment: In which case what you have should work: http://jsfiddle.net/R8sQp/

Comment: If you `console.log(data)` and it is a string instead of an object, then you are not passing the data back from the server correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, there is an array of items. You must iterate that to get to the productId.

```
for( var i = 0; i < item.length; i++ ){
 console.log(item[i].productId);
}
```

*edit*

It is possible that your data is still a string, in which case, you may want to use

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

before iterating. (more on parse: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse )

like this (you could also test to see if it were a string first):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: linktopage,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if( typeof data == "string" )data = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                alert(item.productId);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        }
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right Travis the received JSON was a string and I need to Parse it before I can use it. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

The data is a string entry in your case. So you have to parse it to a JSON first.
Update you code to this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: linktopage,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                var dta = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(dta , function (index, item) {
                    alert(item.productId);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            }
        });
```